# Remove author archive

Tags: archives, author

I'm using wordpress as a CMS.  Various users on the staff write posts that get incorporated into pages manually.

As far as the outside world is concerned, this is just a bunch of static pages.  I want to remove all concept of Authorship, Categories, etc.  It's come to my attention that I can browse to domain.com/author/userName and see the author archive.

How do I disable this?  I would like it to return a 404.

Comment: Just a note: the term "*using WordPress as a CMS*" is tautological. WordPress *is* a CMS.

Answer (score 4):

I would filter `template_redirect`, with an [`is_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) conditional, e.g.:

```
function theme_slug_redirect_author_archive() {
    if ( is_author() ) {
        // Put your redirect code here;
        // Redirect to home_url(), or 
        // return a 404, or whatever
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'theme_slug_redirect_author_archive' );
```

Comment: This is great, but `is_404()` still returns false. Any way to trick WP into thinking it's really a 404?